# New CORS policy for Instagram API?

Tags: cors, fetch, instagram-api

I had some code suddenly break on me around 02/13/19, and it looks like the cause is a CORS issue on the Instagram API Endpoint GET/users/self/media/recent. Everything was working fine on 02/12/19, two days later the CORS issue comes up every time.

The same GET request works without issue when plugged into Postman or Chrome browser, so it's not some error with the request itself that's causing the CORS issue. I've tried replacing the Instagram endpoint with other API endpoints, and there's no problems there. The CORS issue occurs when making the request from localhost as shown below or the website itself.

```
Access to fetch at
'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/
self/media/recent/?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&count=6' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch 
the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I would once I built the page (I'm using ReactJS) and published it I could expect it to work until my access token expired. Instead, a CORS issue appeared overnight. I'm led to believe this is a change Facebook made to their Instagram API, and not due to an issue with the code.

Comment: I've noticed this as well. It seems to only be broken for my local development, but I haven't been able to test outside of that yet.

Comment: the fixed it. It works again ^^

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

this may be a hassle but the ?__a=1 still works but I used a Java Program to call Instagram. Here's an example of the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        //URL url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=arraylist_thesis&result_type=recent");
        URL url = new URL("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/animolasalle/?__a=1");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

The output would be like this.
[Instagram call in Java Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LLi7.png)

I would guess we would have to make a REST server of our own to call the URL.
I hope this helps as I just found out this problem this morning.

Comment: That's what I wound up doing. I wound up creating a php script to handle the request coming from my website, which in turn runs the API request through a python script (I tried running the API request through the php script but also encountered CORS issues). Then all the information gets sent back the other way. I'll upload the code if anyone wants it.